# $\mathbb Z^n$ as a proper quotient of $\mathbb Z^m$

Tags: group-theory

This question is the successor of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976546/mathbb-zn-as-a-quotient-of-mathbb-zm).

Assume that the group $\mathbb Z^n$ is obtained as the quotient $\mathbb Z^m/H$ of $\mathbb Z^m$ for a **non-trivial** subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z^m$. That is, the quotient is **proper**.

Prove that $n\le m-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Say $a=(a_1,\ldots, a_m)\in H$. If, say, $a_1=\pm 1$, then we can form a new basis of $\mathbb Z^m$ using $a, a_2,\ldots, a_m$. Then, killing this vector reduces the dimension by $1$, so killing all of $H$ reduces the dimension by at least $1$, by your previous problem, since you would be quotienting $\mathbb Z^{m-1}$ by the image of $H$ in this intermediate quotient.

So now assume all elements of $H$ fail to have $\pm 1$'s in any of the coordinates, and let $a=(a_1,\ldots, a_m)$ be a nonzero element of $H$. Then the element $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ will be nonzero in the quotient (since it is not in $H$ by assumption), but multiplying it by the least common multiple of the nonzero coordinates of $a$ will send it into $H$ and thus to $0$ is the quotient group, contradicting the quotient being torsion free.

Thus, a proper free quotient must have strictly smaller dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Tensoring with $\mathbb Q$ helps, also in the following down-to-earth variant:
By assumtion, we have a group epimorphism $\alpha\colon \mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb Z^m$ with nontrivial kernel $H$. Then $\alpha$ can be described by an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries, which we may interprete as a matrix in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb Q)$. The rows must be independent for the map to be onto (via multiplication with the lcm of denominators, $\mathbb Q$-independence and $\mathbb Z$-independence are the same). On the other hand, if $h$ is a nonzero element of $h$, some non-trivial linear combination of the columns is zero, i.e. the columns are dependant. We conclude $n>\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb Q}(A)=m$.

Answer (score 0):

Any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ is of the form $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for some $k$. So consider the exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}^k \to \mathbb{Z}^m \to \mathbb{Z}^n \to 0
$$
What happens when you tensor this with $\mathbb{Q}$ (which yields an exact sequence of vector spaces), and check dimensions?

Comment: I don't think that the fact you get an exact sequence when tensoring is as trivial as that... (Basically $\mathrm{Tor}(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathbb{Q}) = 0$)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Then localize instead!

Comment: @Slade it's the same problem, and anyway here it works, it's just that I don't expect a beginner to really know this fact (ie. not just blindly assume it's true).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The same problem how?  Localization is always exact.  But you can also see quite clearly that the induced map is injective, by clearing denominators.  The problem isn't facts, it's language—this exact sequence argument is elegant, clean, precise, and likely to be preferred by veterans, but it's also equivalent to a very elementary proof.  I agree that a beginner might not grasp the meaning of this argument, but this is not due to any sort of advanced machinery, rather an advanced presentation of basic machinery.

Comment: @Slade Tensoring by $\mathbb{Q}$ is localizing at $(0)$. I will ignore the pseudo-philosophical rant.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi ...and localization is exact, always, for fairly elementary reasons (clearing denominators).